# How do I convert an XML file to JSON without overflowing the stack?

Tags: json, xml, rust

I have a huge XML file almost 500MB size. I want to process it and convert it to JSON format with Rust. I have this code but it says :

> thread 'main' has overflowed its stack error: process didn't exit
>   successfully: `target\debug\epg_to_json_to_db.exe` (exit code:
>   0xc00000fd, STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW)

This is my code:

```
extern crate xmlJSON;
extern crate rustc_serialize;
use crate::rustc_serialize::json::ToJson;

use xmlJSON::XmlDocument;
use rustc_serialize::json;
use std::str::FromStr;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let filename = "myfile.xml";

    let mut f = File::open(filename).expect("file not found");

    let mut contents = String::new();
    f.read_to_string(&mut contents).expect("something went wrong reading the file");

    let document: XmlDocument = XmlDocument::from_str(&mut contents).unwrap();
    let jsn: json::Json = document.to_json(); 
    println!("{}", jsn);
}
```

What is a good solution here?

Comment: I suspect the culprit to be that crate `xmlJSON`, as the standard library would generally handle reading a file of that size to a `String` well. Might be worth looking for alternative libraries, such as [`quick-xml`](https://crates.io/crates/quick-xml) or [`sxd-document`](https://crates.io/crates/sxd-document). [`serde`](https://serde.rs) is also a common preference over `rustc_serialize` these days.

Comment: As the author of sxd-document, it *may* not be the right solution here. As the name suggests, it creates an entire in-memory document of the XML. This is generally not something you want to do when processing giant blobs of XML. Unfortunately, the lightweight streaming parser is not publicly exposed.

Comment: I`m really new in rust. could you please help me fine an example?

Comment: You could do a streaming conversion using XSLT 3.0 -- but it depends a lot on whether you want to create a specific JSON representation, or whether any-old-JSON will do.

Comment: @MichaelKay Is there any example? my XML file is XML format not XSLT. Is there any example about your solution?

Comment: I would need to see your XML input and your desired JSON output; a transformation that converts a different XML to a different JSON wouldn't be much use to you (except as a generic example of XSLT coding, for which there are a zillion examples available).